# different sessions in same browser for same web application having different paths

Tags: php

i create a web application and deploy twice on same server on different paths
like 1 **/projects/abc/** , 2 **/projects/xyz/**

when i login at /projects/abc/ in browser and echo the session it give proper results 
when i open another tab and login /projects/xyz/ and echo then it echo proper results

but then when i refresh /projects/abc/ then it echo /projects/xyz/ results.

so i want to set session according to path , and want to know how it can be done?

Comment: The last session will be the one used.

Comment: think about your store logic ... the session is the same, but you can handle it in your store methode ... e.g. use $_SESSION['abc'] and $_SESSION['xyz'] so you can handle on Session for different subdirs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one session with multiple keys

`$_SESSION['projects']['abc'] = 1;`

`$_SESSION['projects']['xyz'] = 2;`